# Error while Expanding Disk Space of virtual machine in Hyper-V server

Tags: windows-server-2008, virtualization, hard-drive, hyper-v

I have one Virtual machine running on my hyper-v server which has allotted the disk space of 100GB, i have only created C drive in this machine and C drive of this machine is fully consumed due to which my website is down. I turned off the machine and tried to expand the hard disk by 100GB for this virtual machine.

I have enough space left on my Hyper-V server.
i clicked on

```
 settings > scsi > given location of my *.vhd file > edit > expand > and expanded the disk size to 200GB > finsh > apply
```

when i clicked to apply after doing all the settings i got the below error.

[image]

I searched for this but most of links which i found they did not pointed me to right direction, links guided me about switching off the vm and then proceed again for expanding this, but i already did this after shutting down the machine. May anyone kindly guide me on this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That's what i am trying to do, expanding the existing .vhd file.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, *disconnect* the VHD from the virtual machine. This implies removing it from the virtual machine configuration, modifying the image, and then re-adding it. This is common to have to do on a lot of hypervisors in some capacity or another just to get the disk info for the VM itself updated. This is a little more extreme, but with the way Windows handles locking I'm not entirely surprised.

So remove the drive > resize the drive > re-add the drive, pointing to the same .VHD. DO NOT delete the file. Just detach it.

Hopefully that works. If it doesn't, I would suspect a bad lock of some kind, but we'll move into that if we have to.

Comment: Thanks for the time and effort made to answer this. Can you please tell how to detach the .VHD file.